# Does swallowing our own mucus breaks the fast

Tags: sawm

Aslamoalaikum to all of my brothers and sisters .. does swallowing our own mucus breaks the fast if yes then it’s impossible for me to not to swallow it while praying salah coz I can’t spit out . I know mostly people spit out but sometimes i swallow it coz i have to much of mucus in my mouth .. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu alaikum,
Hi, if u swallow ur mucus, ur fast wont be broken (ive had this same problem). Anything in ur mouth excep for blood wont break ur fast.
May allah bless u this Ramadan